# Split data in ratio by using column value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

Suppose we have a table with columns A and B. B is the count of values present in A. Eg.,

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 23 |
| 2000 | 50 |
| 4000 | 20 |
| 7000 | 70 |
| 3000 | 64 |

How to split the data with 8:1:1 ratio of column B.

Example:
B is 23. Therefore 8:1:1 of B will be ~ 18,2,3
There will be 18 rows for train, 2 rows for test and 3 rows for val.

Similarly 8:1:1 of 20 will be 16,2,2.

Expected output table:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | Train |
| 1000 | . | Train |
| 1000 | . | Train |
| 1000 | 18 | Train |
| 1000 | 1 | Test |
| 1000 | 2 | Test |
| 1000 | 1 | Val |
| 1000 |  | Val |
| 1000 | 3 | Val |
| 2000 | 1 | Train |
| 2000 | . | Train |
| 2000 | 40 | Train |
| 2000 | 1 | Test |
| 2000 | . | Test |
| 2000 | 5 | Test |
| 2000 | 1 | Val |
| 2000 | . | Val |
| 2000 | 5 | Val |
| 4000 | 1 | Train |
| 4000 | . | Train |
| 4000 | . | Train |
| 4000 | 16 | Train |
| 4000 | 1 | Test |
| 4000 | 2 | Test |
| 4000 | 1 | Val |
| 4000 | 2 | Val |
| 3000 | 1 | Train |
| 3000 | . | Train |
| 3000 | 51 | Train |
| 3000 | 1 | Test |
| 3000 | . | Test |
| 3000 | . | Test |
| 3000 | 6 | Test |
| 3000 | 1 | Val |
| 3000 | . | Val |
| 3000 | 7 | Val |

Shortly, I want to split the rows in train, test, val set in proportion 8:1:1 using column B value.

I tried using Pandas to calculate total count of rows as stated above. But I am not able to split the count into ratio.

Answer (score 0):

```
def spliter(NUM):
  lst = []
  lst.append(int(NUM*0.8))
  lst.append(int(NUM*0.1))
  lst.append(int(NUM*0.1))
  turn = 2
  while(lst[0]+lst[1]+lst[2] != NUM):
    lst[turn] = lst[turn] + 1
    if turn == 0:
      turn = 1
    elif turn == 1:
      turn = 2
    elif turn == 2:
      turn = 0
  return(lst)
```

```
print(spliter(23))
```

Output:

```
[18, 2, 3]
```

So if this is your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Column A' : [1000,2000,4000,7000,3000],
    'Column B'  : [23,50,20,70,64]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   Column A  Column B
0      1000        23
1      2000        50
2      4000        20
3      7000        70
4      3000        64
```

We can reach the desired dataframe in this way:

```
df2 = [[],[],[]]
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
  lst = spliter(df1['Column B'][index])
  for i in range(1,lst[0]+1):
    df2[0].append(df1['Column A'][index])
    df2[1].append(i)
    df2[2].append('Train')
  for i in range(1,lst[1]+1):
    df2[0].append(df1['Column A'][index])
    df2[1].append(i)
    df2[2].append('Test')
  for i in range(1,lst[2]+1):
    df2[0].append(df1['Column A'][index])
    df2[1].append(i)
    df2[2].append('Val')

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Column A','Column B','Column C'])
df3['Column A'] = df2[0]
df3['Column B'] = df2[1]
df3['Column C'] = df2[2]
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
     Column A  Column B Column C
0        1000         1    Train
1        1000         2    Train
2        1000         3    Train
3        1000         4    Train
4        1000         5    Train
..        ...       ...      ...
222      3000         3      Val
223      3000         4      Val
224      3000         5      Val
225      3000         6      Val
226      3000         7      Val

[227 rows x 3 columns]
```